# How to read certain lines from a textfile in python which are now not shown?

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying read lines to determine it's indexes for me to use in another program but one specific line seems to always be passed. Why is this happening?

Here is my text file:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                    Food Ordering System                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  No  |           Food           |          Price          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.   | Burger Set               |         RM11.00         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2.   | Pizza Set                |         RM11.00         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 3.   | Spaghetti Bolognese Set  |         RM12.00         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 4.   | Spaghetti Aglio Set      |         RM13.00         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  No  |         Beverage         |          Price          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.   | Coca-Cola                |                         |
+---------------------------------+                         |
| 2.   | Pepsi                    |   Included in the set   |
+---------------------------------+                         |
| 3.   | Fanta Strawberry         |                         |
+---------------------------------+                         |
| 4.   | Fanta Orange             |                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The one highlighted is the image that is being overlooked

Here is my code and the output:

```
def Testing():
    try:
        data = []
        with open("Menu.txt") as f:
            for line in f:
                if "-" not in line:
                    data.append(line.split("|")[1:-1])

            print(data)
            print((data[7][0]).strip())
            print((data[7][1]).strip())
            print((data[7][2]).strip())

    except TypeError: 
        print("Invalid")

Testing()
```

The Output:

```
[['                    Food Ordering System                   '], ['  No  ', '           Food           ', '          Price          '], [' 1.   ', ' Burger Set               ', '         RM11.00         '], [' 2.   ', ' Pizza Set                ', '         RM11.00         '], [' 3.   ', ' Spaghetti Bolognese Set  ', '         RM12.00         '], [' 4.   ', ' Spaghetti Aglio Set      ', '         RM13.00         '], ['  No  ', '         Beverage         ', '          Price          '], [' 2.   ', ' Pepsi                    ', '   Included in the set   '], [' 3.   ', ' Fanta Strawberry         ', '                         '], [' 4.   ', ' Fanta Orange             ', '                         ']]
2.
Pepsi
Included in the set
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if "-" not in line:
```

skips that line because of the `-` in `Coca-Cola`

It looks like you're trying to skip the dividing lines like

```
+-------------------+
```

You need to use a different condition to skip those lines, so you don't skip lines that contain `-` in the text. For instance:

```
if line.startswith('|'):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `pandas` library, this would be a one-liner (including the splitting into cells), note how this regex specifies a pipe '|' separator with optional surrounding whitespace:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Menu.txt', sep='\s*\|\s*')
```

Now 'Coca-Cola' will be parsed as one string.

(Defining that regex is much harder than it looks. We have to match both *leading* and *trailing* whitespace, and escape the vertical bar so it doesn't get misinterpreted).